# how to change selenium.WebDriver headers after running in golang

Tags: go, selenium-webdriver

selenium.WebDriver after running trying to change the headers

want to change the selenium.Capabilities.prefs.headers on running WebDriver

```
func main() {
    caps := selenium.Capabilities{
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "chromeOptions": map[string]interface{}{
            "args": []string{
                "--disable-extensions",
                "--disable-plugins",
            },
            "prefs": map[string]interface{}{
                "headers": map[string]interface{}{
                    "User-Agent":      "my custom User-Agent",
                    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
                },
            },
        },
    }

    wd, err := selenium.NewRemote(caps, fmt.Sprintf("http://localhost:%d/wd/hub", 4444))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer wd.Quit()

    // here i want to change the headers on wd
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would assume that you're using the package `github.com/tebeka/selenium`.

And the remote WebDriver I used for testing is a docker container:

```
docker run -d -p 4444:4444 --shm-size="2g" selenium/standalone-chrome:111.0-20230328
```

The capabilities key `chromeOptions` was deprecated. And it's not supported by the remote WebDriver created above. I'm not sure whether [pref_names.cc](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:chrome/common/pref_names.cc) has listed the full list of `prefs` keys, but I can not find `headers` on the list, and it's not recognized according to my test. So I change the demo to:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/tebeka/selenium"
    "github.com/tebeka/selenium/chrome"
)

func main() {
    caps := selenium.Capabilities{"browserName": "chrome"}
    caps.AddChrome(chrome.Capabilities{
        // See the list of Chromium Command Line Switches:
        // https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/
        Args: []string{
            // set the User-Agent string with the command line switch --user-agent
            "--user-agent=my custom User-Agent",
            // set the languages with the command line switch --accept-lang
            "--accept-lang=zh-CN,zh",
            "--disable-extensions",
            "--disable-plugins",
        },
        Prefs: map[string]interface{}{
            // The purpose is to show that the names listed in the following file works:
            // https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:chrome/common/pref_names.cc
            "enable_do_not_track": true,
        },
    })

    wd, err := selenium.NewRemote(caps, fmt.Sprintf("http://localhost:%d/wd/hub", 4444))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer wd.Quit()

    if err := wd.Get("https://httpbin.org/headers"); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    pre, err := wd.FindElement(selenium.ByCSSSelector, "pre")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    content, err := pre.Text()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(content)
}
```

Here is the output:

```json
{
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br", 
    "Accept-Language": "zh-CN,zh;q=0.9", 
    "Dnt": "1", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "Sec-Ch-Ua": "\"Google Chrome\";v=\"111\", \"Not(A:Brand\";v=\"8\", \"Chromium\";v=\"111\"", 
    "Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile": "?0", 
    "Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform": "\"Linux\"", 
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document", 
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate", 
    "Sec-Fetch-Site": "none", 
    "Sec-Fetch-User": "?1", 
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1", 
    "User-Agent": "my custom User-Agent", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-64268e31-1b3b2f18211c1b2b11862032"
  }
}
```

Now regarding your question about changing the `User-Agent` and `Accept-Language` headers on the fly, as far as I know, it's not supported by [webdriver](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver). But [Selenium 4 provides direct access to the Chrome DevTools Protocol (CDP)](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/bidirectional/chrome_devtools/), which has the command [Emulation.setUserAgentOverride](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Emulation/#method-setUserAgentOverride) to change those headers. The bad news is that the package `github.com/tebeka/selenium` has not implemented the CDP feature yet. So the answer for your question is: no, it's impossible to change `wd` to send requests with different `User-Agent` and `Accept-Language` headers.

In case you didn't know, the package `github.com/chromedp/chromedp` is a faster, simpler way to drive browsers supporting the Chrome DevTools Protocol. It's not a replacement of Selenium, but it shines in some of the use cases. For example, the scenario described in the question can be implemented as:

**Disclosure: I'm one of the maintainers of the package `github.com/chromedp/chromedp`**.

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/chromedp/cdproto/emulation"
    "github.com/chromedp/chromedp"
)

func main() {
    opts := append(chromedp.DefaultExecAllocatorOptions[:],
        chromedp.Flag("headless", "new"),
        chromedp.UserAgent("my custom User-Agent"),
        chromedp.Flag("accept-lang", "zh-CN,zh"),
    )
    ctx, cancel := chromedp.NewExecAllocator(context.Background(), opts...)
    defer cancel()

    ctx, cancel = chromedp.NewContext(ctx)
    defer cancel()

    var content string
    if err := chromedp.Run(ctx,
        chromedp.Navigate("https://httpbin.org/headers"),
        chromedp.Text("pre", &content, chromedp.ByQuery),
        chromedp.ActionFunc(func(ctx context.Context) error {
            fmt.Println(content)
            return nil
        }),
        // Change the User-Agent and Accept-Language headers.
        emulation.SetUserAgentOverride("my custom User-Agent 2").
            WithAcceptLanguage("th-TH,th"),
        chromedp.Navigate("https://httpbin.org/headers"),
        chromedp.Text("pre", &content, chromedp.ByQuery),
        chromedp.ActionFunc(func(ctx context.Context) error {
            fmt.Println(content)
            return nil
        }),
    ); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
{
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br", 
    "Accept-Language": "zh-CN,zh;q=0.9", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "Sec-Ch-Ua": "\"Google Chrome\";v=\"111\", \"Not(A:Brand\";v=\"8\", \"Chromium\";v=\"111\"", 
    "Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile": "?0", 
    "Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform": "\"Linux\"", 
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document", 
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate", 
    "Sec-Fetch-Site": "none", 
    "Sec-Fetch-User": "?1", 
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1", 
    "User-Agent": "my custom User-Agent", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-64269a20-5b8b73b145ce666314897f1f"
  }
}

{
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br", 
    "Accept-Language": "th-TH,th;q=0.9", 
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=0", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document", 
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate", 
    "Sec-Fetch-Site": "none", 
    "Sec-Fetch-User": "?1", 
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1", 
    "User-Agent": "my custom User-Agent 2", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-64269a20-291bad6143d5f1dc687b92d4"
  }
}
```

Comment: i tried chromedp its good project but i didnt find how to run serveral chrome browser simultaneously     selenium can use serveral diff port to control browser

Comment: `ctx1, cancel := chromedp.NewContext(context.Background())
chromedp.Run(ctx1)
ctx2, cancel := chromedp.NewContext(context.Background())
chromedp.Run(ctx2)`

It's easy, but it's not encouraged. Because it's slow and consumes more resources. It's  recommended to open several tabs instead.